# displaying a custom map and placing pin/images on the map

Tags: java, android, xml, dictionary

i wanted to create a directory app for a grocery. i already have the floor plan of the place. i just wanted to display it in a view and i want to put some markers/pins/images to it.. i have no idea where to start. someone told me to use bitmap and canvass but i have no idea how to use it as the other tutorials in google is quite vague and hard to understand..

what my app requires:

- display a custom map from an image source
- enable me to put markers,pins and some images on top of it

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use use ImageView:

//make a bitmap from your floorPlanImage, example from file
`Bitmap floorPlanImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);`
//make a mutable bitmap, so it can be changed
`Bitmap mutableFloorPlanImage = floorPlanImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);`
//create a canvas to draw on your floorPlanImage
`Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mutableFloorPlanImage);`
//draw a marker or another image on the floorPlanImage, you can position it using left and top //coordinates, in this example both 0
`mCanvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, 0, 0, null);`
//show the resulting bitmap in ImageView
`imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableFloorPlanImage);`